# selenium simple test says xpath is not a legal expression

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I started using SST (selenium simple test) but ran into a problem when executing what seems to be a valid xpath expression `'//div[div@data-type="folder-name"]'`. SST fails with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sst/cases.py", line 207, in run_test_script exec self.code in self.context
File "./sst-one.py", line 7, in <module> names = get_elements_by_xpath('//div[div@data-type="folder-name"]')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sst/actions.py", line 1344, in >get_elements_by_xpath_raise(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sst/actions.py", line 118, in _raise raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Element not found: Message: u'The given selector //div[div@data->type="folder-name"] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following >error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath >expression //div[div@data-type="folder-name"] because of the following >error:\n[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: >"0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js> Line: 5916"]' ;
Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8873)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementsInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8931)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElements file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8935)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10840)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10845)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< file:///tmp/tmp12zCta/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10787)
```

The SST code line is:

```
names = get_elements_by_xpath('//div[div@data-type="folder-name"]')
```

If I run the same xpath statement using selenium (from python), not SST, it is a valid expression and returns the matching elements if there were any.

The pure selenium code line (where br is the firefox webdriver object) is:

```
elems = br.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[div/@data-type='folder-name']")
```

I understand this is a bit in the weeds, so if anyone has some hints as to how to debug the .js code that selenium creates in the /tmp directory that would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a valid XPath expression. This

```
//div[div@data-type="folder-name"]
```

Should probably read

```
//div[div/@data-type="folder-name"]
```

which is indeed what you have in one of your examples.

Comment: Thank you Michael Kay. It is so obvious now but for some reason I have been unable to see this.

Comment: Is `div/@data-type="folder-name"` means all the children of the outside `div` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any markup, up i assuming you have

`<div><div data-type="folder-name"></div></div>`

you need:

```
elems = br.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//div[@data-type='folder-name']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all possible div tags with data-type="folder-name",

```
//div[@data-type="folder-name"]
```

If only children of the first div with data-type="folder-name",

```
//div[div/@data-type="folder-name"]
```